# How to remove the 2nd element of every tuple that belongs to a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

I have a list of tuples that look like this;

```
ListTuple=[('Tuple1', '2ndElement', '3rdElement', 1L), ('Tuple2', '2ndElement', '3rdElement', 2L)]
```

I want to remove the 2nd element from every tuple inside this list of tuples. The output will look like this;

```
OutputTuple=[('Tuple1', '3rdElement', 1L), ('Tuple2', '3rdElement', 2L)]
```

How can this be done in python? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`OutputTuple = [(a, b, d) for a, b, c, d in ListTuple]`

Oh and btw, since these are tuples (immutables), you can't "remove" stuff from them. Only create something new.

Comment: You make it look so simple. As usual, I feel like a damn fool. The other answers are right too. Yours is the most readable for idiots like me. Thanks!!

Comment: @user3293156: That's python for you! Was glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

*Keep* everything *but* the second item.

```
In [4]: [(t[0], t[2], t[3]) for t in ListTuple]
Out[4]: [('Tuple1', '3rdElement', 1L), ('Tuple2', '3rdElement', 2L)]
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution works without assuming a fixed number of elements in each tuple, or even that there is the same number of elements in each tuple.

```
ListTuple=[('Tuple1', '2ndElement', '3rdElement', 1L), ('Tuple2', '2ndElement', '3rdElement', 2L)]
output = [((t[0],)+t[2:]) for t in ListTuple]
```